# How to connect to local NAS through web browser with no internet?

Tags: mac, nas, intranet

My apologies if this is not the correct forum to post my question.  I am setting up a new Synology NAS in my studio where I have no internet.  I have two computers and a wireless router.  My Mac desktop computer is connected directly to the router via ethernet and the NAS is connected to the router via ethernet.  My Mac laptop connects to the router wirelessly over the local wi-fi network.  As things are right now, I am able to navigate to the files on the NAS from both computers through the Finder.  However, I am not able to navigate to the web browser of the NAS when I put in the IP address for the NAS.

I don't know much about networking at all.  When I set up the NAS and installed the software, I needed internet access, and so I brought the NAS home and connected it to my home internet router and I was able to navigate right to the NAS through the browser and install the software.  I took a screenshot of the IP there.  IP was 192.168.1.133:5000.

I took the NAS back to the studio and tried the same IP in the browser on the studio computer and I did not get a connection.  I'm not sure if it matters that the studio is a different router than the one at the house?  I'm also simply not sure if navigating to a local IP address on a browser on a computer with no internet connection works?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have AP isolation on?

Comment: Do you use the Synology Assistant to find synology in the local network? (just in case your Synology NAS ended up with a different IP address)

Comment: *"I am not able to navigate to the web browser of the NAS"* -- The *browser* would be on your PC/laptop.  You're trying to connect to the web *server* of the NAS.  Have you logged into the wireless router, and gotten a status report of connected devices?

Comment: I can log in to the router.  I'm not sure how to get a status report.  It's a netgear router.  I will look on the left side to see if that is an option...  I'm not sure what AP Isolation is (googling now)...I didn't use synology assistant to get onto the NAS when I brought it home, so I didn't think to install it.  I can bring the NAS back to the house if I need Synology Assistant.  
Should I assume that if I can see the files in finder, but not navigate to the server theough the browser that I am using the wrong IP?  Do I need to open the port or anything to access :5000?

Comment: Did you configure the device for DHCP, or have you set the .1.133 address statically? if so, confirm your wireless network is using 192.168.1.X as its IP range. if not, then the device is getting a differant IP address on each network, so the IP you saw when on the Internet connected network will have changed when you plugged it in in the studio. which is the case here?

Comment: I'm hoping that Synology Assistant will shed some light on it.  I'm going to the studio in the morning to install it on the Mac.  To be clear-the Mac is connecting to the NAS through the Router purely through ethernet cables-the wi-fi network is completely shut off.  I am able to put in 192.168.1.1 and get to the router settings.

Comment: ok that implies wireless client isolation. disable it on the router.

Comment: Installing Synology Assistant did the trick.  It was set to DHCP and had changed IP addresses without me realizing.  Thanks for your help everyone!